# How solr behaves for empty index fields?

Tags: solr

I have a number of index fields in solr schema. Some of these are filled on  regular basis on indexing content into solr. But some of these are filled conditionally such as if field name is available in source, index it and fill it in index field otherwise leave it empty.

How solr behaves in these scenarios. Do i get all fields with/without values in solr index or i will see only those index fields which are non-empty. I think later scenario should hold true.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is not marked as required then it will simply be missing from the document, and queries on those field will miss the document in question.

Comment: But you can still query for documents having no value in this field.

Comment: if your doc looks like this {"foo":"bar", "foo2":"baz"} and your query like this : "foo3:*", the document will not match

Comment: Which is completely correct; but you may be interested in all object having null in a field, and retrieve them via `-foo3:*`. This may have some business significance, and I just wanted to state, that these documents are not completely lost ;o)

Comment: So these fields will not be present in index.

Comment: I don't think i understand your statement

Comment: I meant to say that only those index fields which have some values against them will be available for search and fields with nil/empty values will not be available for search as well as these fields will not be present in index while checked using solr admin client.